# Using Which and Switch in a function

Tags: functions

I'm having hard time trying to make use of `Which` or `Switch`. I'm trying

```
f[n_Integer] := Witch[
    n == 0, "zero"
  , n == 1, "one"
  , EvenQ[n], "even"
  , OddQ[n], "odd"
  , True, n
  ]
```

and

```
f[n_Integer] := Switch[n
  , 0, "zero"
  , 1, "one"
  , _Even, "even"
  , _Odd, "odd"
  , _, n
  ]
```

Neither of them works. What am I missing?

Comment: You need `Which` instead of `Witch`.  Also, `_Even` will only match something with `Even` as a head, like `Even[3]` or `Even[x]`, I think there you want `_?EvenQ` and `_?OddQ`

Comment: @JasonB., yes you right on both accounts. Please make it the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a simple typo, `Witch` instead of `Which`.  The second issue is with a malformed pattern, `_Even`, which will only match something with the head `Even` like `Even[x]`.  You need to use something like `_?EvenQ` where `EvenQ` is a single-argument function that returns `True` or `False`.

See [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) and [this pattern tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) for more information.

```
fswitch[n_Integer] := 
  Switch[n, 
    0, "zero", 
    1, "one", 
    _?EvenQ, "even", 
    _?OddQ, "odd", 
    _, n
  ];

fwhich[n_Integer] := 
  Which[
    Equal[n, 0], "zero",
    Equal[n, 1], "one",
    EvenQ[n], "even",
    OddQ[n], "odd",
    True, n
  ]; 

fwhich /@ Range[6]
(* {"one", "even", "odd", "even", "odd", "even"} *)

fswitch /@ Range[6]
(* {"one", "even", "odd", "even", "odd", "even"} *)
```